# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'id' - Django Oscar Paypal?

Tags: django, paypal, django-oscar

Trying to integrate [Django-Oscar-Paypal](https://django-oscar-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with my project. I'm using Paypal express version. On checkout the flow is going to Paypal's site. But when the Paypal redirects back to my site I'm getting the following error.

```
AttributeError at /checkout/paypal/preview/16/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/checkout/paypal/preview/16/?token=EC-9JB96808VX198132S&PayerID=TYNFGLXS46S2E
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'id'
Exception Location: /Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/apps/offer/applicator.py in get_basket_offers, line 93
Python Executable:  /Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/Users/nikhilsingh/teabox_new/teashop',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/nikhilsingh/djangoOscarEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 5 Oct 2015 07:10:10 +0000
```

It seems like the basket gets empty on redirection hence no `id` is found. What can I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: This solved the issue : https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal/issues/104

Comment: It is fixed latest version